# How to manage errors with STOMP

Tags: reactjs, stomp, stompjs

I'm wondering if there is a native way to **manage errors** received by STOMP on the client side like you could with fetch? I currently use `@stomp/stompjs` and have to manage some errors after a publish to the backend was rejected, like if an action is not permitted. But besides the error message in the console (if debug is enabled) there is no other way to see the error, especially not to handle them, or is there?